# Cannot open file 'SDL2.lib' and Cannot open file 'uctrtd.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQAXYN_9Yzc&feature=youtu.be) tutorial to get SDL working. I've followed the steps he outlined:

In my properties under VC++ Directories I have:

```
Include Directories
C:\SDL2-2.0.4\include;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt;
$(IncludePath)

Library Directories
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt;
C:\SDL2-2.0.4\lib;
$(LibraryPath)
```

Under Linker > General I have:

```
Additional Library Directories
%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

I also have `SDL2.dll` placed in `E:\Dev\cpp\SDL Setup\MyProject\Debug`

When I have it like this I get the error `Cannot open file 'SDL2.lib'` **but** if I set the directory to the SDL lib (I.E. `C:\SDL2-2.0.4\lib\x64`) it no longer displays the error but *then* shows the error `Cannot open file 'uctrtd.lib'`.

I'm not sure if that error is a step in the right direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From your post, it is evident that LIB files are present at:

```
C:\SDL2-2.0.4\lib\x64;
```

and not at:

```
C:\SDL2-2.0.4\lib;
```

So, you must use the `x64` path to get the lib. It is also visible that `.LIB` for 64-bit are present in `x64` folder, and there must be something for 32-bit linking (in `C:\SDL2-2.0.4\lib` itself) - for you 32-bit build.

Please fix it gradually, calmly and in step-by-step manner.

The error you are later getting for `uctrtd.lib` is probably because you messed up standard LIB paths. Bring the original LIB paths back, and append this library's LIB path.

Comment: There were no original paths to mess up. All the paths where blank when I started. I had to manually find where stdio etc. was and input the path VS.